# How to get just value from an array of object with condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question. I am trying to write but failed. I need your help. Please help me.

Suppose I have a `array` of object-

```
const movieGen = [
    { id: 28, name: "Action" }, { id: 12, name: "Adventure" }, { id: 16, name: "Animation" },
    { id: 35, name: "Comedy" }, { id: 80, name: "Crime" }, { id: 99, name: "Documentary" },
    { id: 18, name: "Drama" }, { id: 10751, name: "Family" }, { id: 14, name: "Fantasy" },
    { id: 36, name: "History" }, { id: 27, name: "Horror" }, { id: 10402, name: "Music" },
    { id: 9648, name: "Mystery" }, { id: 10749, name: "Romance" }, { id: 878, name: "Science Fiction" },
    { id: 10770, name: "TV Movie" }, { id: 53, name: "Thriller" }, { id: 10752, name: "War" },
    { id: 37, name: "Western" }
]
```

Here I need one function. That function should be worked as when `id` is matched then return the `name`. Like-

const genresHandler = (id: number) => {
....//Here should be the function
}

When I provide `28` as `id` to this function it should return `Action`

```
console.log(genresHandler(28))   output should be: Action
console.log(genresHandler(12))   output should be: Adventure
```

Please help me to write this function in `typscript` or `javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

```
const genresHandler = (movieId) => {
  const movie = movieGen.find((movie) => movie.id === movieId);
  return movie ? movie.name : null;
}
```

Best way to traverse the movies inside the `movieGen` array is to use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function which takes a callback function that compares and returns the first movie entry that contains an `id` that is the same as the one that is passed into the `genresHandler` function (`movieId`). The result of find is then placed inside a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which returns the `name` of the movie if one has been found (is defined), or `null` if one has not been found.

Comment: No, no. `Action` and `Adventure` not hard coded. It should return that object name field value.

Comment: You see that every object of that array has two field. One is `id` and the other is `name`. My question is that the function should be return `name` when `id` is matched to the provided `id`.

Comment: My apologies, i made the edit

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate the object with the matching `id` and return the `name` value.

The `?` refers to a relatively new feature in JavaScript called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It basically means if the object is found return the name otherwise return a default message.

```js
const arr=[{id:28,name:"Action"},{id:12,name:"Adventure"},{id:16,name:"Animation"},{id:35,name:"Comedy"},{id:80,name:"Crime"},{id:99,name:"Documentary"},{id:18,name:"Drama"},{id:10751,name:"Family"},{id:14,name:"Fantasy"},{id:36,name:"History"},{id:27,name:"Horror"},{id:10402,name:"Music"},{id:9648,name:"Mystery"},{id:10749,name:"Romance"},{id:878,name:"Science Fiction"},{id:10770,name:"TV Movie"},{id:53,name:"Thriller"},{id:10752,name:"War"},{id:37,name:"Western"}];

function getGenre(arr, id) {
  return arr.find(movie => {
    return movie.id === id;
  })?.name || 'No genre found';
}

console.log(getGenre(arr, 28));
console.log(getGenre(arr, 12));
console.log(getGenre(arr, 1));
```

If you wanted to be fancy you could pass in an array of ids and get *all* the genres. You would [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the objects where the ids array contains the movie id (returns an array of movie objects), and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return only the names from those objects.

```js
const arr=[{id:28,name:"Action"},{id:12,name:"Adventure"},{id:16,name:"Animation"},{id:35,name:"Comedy"},{id:80,name:"Crime"},{id:99,name:"Documentary"},{id:18,name:"Drama"},{id:10751,name:"Family"},{id:14,name:"Fantasy"},{id:36,name:"History"},{id:27,name:"Horror"},{id:10402,name:"Music"},{id:9648,name:"Mystery"},{id:10749,name:"Romance"},{id:878,name:"Science Fiction"},{id:10770,name:"TV Movie"},{id:53,name:"Thriller"},{id:10752,name:"War"},{id:37,name:"Western"}];

function getGenre(arr, ids) {
  return arr
    .filter(movie => ids.includes(movie.id))
    .map(movie => movie.name);
}

console.log(getGenre(arr, [28, 12, 9648, 1]));
```

Comment: If `id` is not in `arr`, `getGenre` function will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript:

```
const movieGen = [
{ id: 28, name: "Action" }, { id: 12, name: "Adventure" }, { id: 16, name: "Animation" },
{ id: 35, name: "Comedy" }, { id: 80, name: "Crime" }, { id: 99, name: "Documentary" },
{ id: 18, name: "Drama" }, { id: 10751, name: "Family" }, { id: 14, name: "Fantasy" },
{ id: 36, name: "History" }, { id: 27, name: "Horror" }, { id: 10402, name: "Music" },
{ id: 9648, name: "Mystery" }, { id: 10749, name: "Romance" }, { id: 878, name: "Science Fiction" },
{ id: 10770, name: "TV Movie" }, { id: 53, name: "Thriller" }, { id: 10752, name: "War" },
{ id: 37, name: "Western" }
];

function test(id) {
  const res = movieGen.filter(el => el.id == id);
  console.log(res[0].name);
}

test(28);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the object using [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Return a specific property :

```js
const movieGen = [{id:28, name: "Action" }, {id:12,name:"Adventure"}, { id: 16, name: "Animation"}];
const genresHandler = (movieId) =>
movieGen.find((movie) => movie.id === movieId)?.name ?? ''

console.log(genresHandler(28));
console.log(genresHandler(29));
console.log(genresHandler(12));
```

You can use [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to handle cases when item does not exist. With optional chaining you can try to access nested properties (which might not exist) of an object without nested if conditions

Answer (score 0):

```js
const genresHandler = (id) => {
    const found = movieGen.find(movie => movie.id === id)
    // if found, return the name, if not, return null
    return found ? found.name : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const movieGen = [
    { id: 28, name: "Action" }, { id: 12, name: "Adventure" }, { id: 16, name: "Animation" },
    { id: 35, name: "Comedy" }, { id: 80, name: "Crime" }, { id: 99, name: "Documentary" },
    { id: 18, name: "Drama" }, { id: 10751, name: "Family" }, { id: 14, name: "Fantasy" },
    { id: 36, name: "History" }, { id: 27, name: "Horror" }, { id: 10402, name: "Music" },
    { id: 9648, name: "Mystery" }, { id: 10749, name: "Romance" }, { id: 878, name: "Science Fiction" },
    { id: 10770, name: "TV Movie" }, { id: 53, name: "Thriller" }, { id: 10752, name: "War" },
    { id: 37, name: "Western" }
  ]

var data = movieGen.filter(item => item.id === parseInt(28)); // pass your value instade of 28
data.map(matchItem => console.log(matchItem))
```